# Month and Day in a Date are Sometimes Reversed when Copied in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, loops, transpose

**My Problem:**

I have made a For Each loop, which Loops through 2 different columns in the same sheet.
This loop copies the desired columns, and the unique values.
Althought the macro works, it will paste a wrong date.
How it pastes a wrong date, is specified under the section "Goal:".

**My Table:**

`|    Date    |    ColB     |    Amount   |    Date    |    ColG     |    Amount   |`
`| 02-08-2018 |   V584753   |     500     | 02-08-2018 |   V584753   |     -500    |`
`| 11-08-2018 |   486542    |    1.000    | 21-08-2018 |   439857    |   -30.547   |`
`| 21-08-2018 |   439857    |   30.547    | 31-08-2018 |   V587742   |    -1.059   |`

**My Code:**

```
Sub PasteCellsWithoutMatch()

Dim ColB As Range, ColG As Range, c As Range
Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction
Set Wf = WorksheetFunction
Dim vR() As Variant
Dim k As Long, j As Integer

For Each c In ColB.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        With Wf
            n = .CountIfs(ColG, c)
            If n = 0 Then
                k = k + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 3, 1 To k)
                For j = 1 To 3
                    vR(j, k) = c.Offset(0, j - 2)
                Next j
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

Sheet("Match").Range("A1").Resize(k, 3) = Wf.Transpose(vR)
```

**Goal:**

What I mean by "pasting the wrong date", the code will swaps the "dd-mm-yyyy" to "mm-dd-yyyy" whenever the first value is below 12.

Meaning that: 02-08-2018
Becomes: **08-02-2018**

Whereas: 13-08-2018
Remains: **13-08-2018**

How can I correct this error?
If there is any correction to it.

*Thank you in advance, for your help.*

Comment: Depends what your requirement is. If you are happy to have the values in text format, simple solution would be to add apostrophe at the start and excel will take your values as text and wont change anything. On the other hand, if you want it in date format.. bit more complicated

Comment: Dates are in fact integer values, so it's simply a matter of changing the numberformat of the target cell. Small note - your `With Wf` is obsolete, you only reference it once in the whole block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution myself.**

First of all, thank you for you efforts, but I couldn't really get myself to try them, since I needed to change to much in my formula...

Before looping through the cells, I removed the date format from the date columns.
Whereas turning it into to general, the transpose won't swap the numbers around.

```html
RngNavRange = "A3:A" & LastRowA
RngKvikRange = "F3:F" & LastRowF

Range(RngNavRange).NumberFormat = "General"
Range(RngKvikRange).NumberFormat = "General"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replicating the problem with minimal code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim val1 As String: val1 = "02/08/2018"
    Dim val2 As String: val2 = "13/08/2018"
    Dim myInput1 As Date
    Dim myInput2 As Date

    myInput1 = val1
    myInput2 = val2

    Range("A1") = myInput1
    Range("A2") = myInput2

End Sub
```

Gets this:

[image]

---

One possible solution is using `DateSerial()`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim val1 As String: val1 = "02/08/2018"
    Dim val2 As String: val2 = "13/08/2018"
    Dim myInput1 As Date
    Dim myInput2 As Date

    myInput1 = DateSerial(Split(val1, "/")(2), Split(val1, "/")(1), Split(val1, "/")(0))
    myInput2 = DateSerial(Split(val2, "/")(2), Split(val2, "/")(1), Split(val2, "/")(0))

    Range("A1") = myInput1
    Range("A2") = myInput2

End Sub
```

For some advanced solution, you may consider either writing a customized function or changing a bit the regional settings. The latter is dangerous.

Comment: Okay, I must correct what I wrote. It doesn't change the format, it just swaps date and month, but it will then show as the 8th of February. No matter how many times I'll try to change the format, it will still be the 8th of February.

Comment: @Patrick S - try the 2 snippets I wrote, the first one literally does what you are saying.

Comment: I just cannot see how it should work, since you name the strings as "02/08/2018". It won't be that every time, next month it will be 06-09-2018 turning into 09-06-2018, and the month after that another one again.

Comment: @PatrickS - try it twice. The first piece replicates exactly the problem you are facing.

Comment: Meaning that 02-08-2018 is just to show VBA, how it should be "formatted"?
How would you then put it in? Before I transpose the 3 cells? :)

Comment: @PatrickS - the transpose does not have to do with it. Have you tried copy+paste the code above?

Comment: The transpose is made, since my loop stores the unique lines within the transpose. The perfect thing about the transpose, is that my loop "vR()" stores the unique values from date to amount. Meaning that the transpose just inserts the values I need on the other sheet. But if I understand you correctly, your suggestion is that I drop the transpose, and add something to my loop that whenever it finds a unique value, it should copy from date to amount and insert it on the other sheet?

Comment: On the other hand, the one sheet, that the has all of my data (Date, ColB, Amount etc.), has the right date, but whenever I transpose it, it converts into what I've described above.

Comment: @PatrickS - the issue with the date, that is faced is irrelevant to the transpose. E.g., the first part of the code I have posted replicates it completely. If you try to solve it locally, then you can build up later with transpose and etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your local settings. Anyway, macro doesn't look into local at all.
So you can overpass it by using format function.
For example:

```
val1="02/08/2018"
val2=format(cdate(val1),"ddmmyyyy"))
```

It's gonna work